# Powershell get-content, foreach

Tags: powershell, foreach, active-directory

I've written a Powershell script to prompt for an Active Directory username, and then add the user to relevant AD groups based on which email server the mailbox is hosted on.

This works great but I'm looking to automate this even further by importing a list of AD usernames from a text file. I've been looking at `Get-Content` and `Foreach` but not having much success.

Can anyone show me the correct methods please?

```
$list = Get-Content "C:\users.txt"
Foreach ($user in $list) { 
    #Original code to prompt
    #$user = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the username'
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "Staff" -Member $user
    $HomeMDB = Get-ADuser $user -Properties * | Select *HomeMDB*
    if ($HomeMDB -like '*Email_Ser1*') {
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "Email_Server1" -Member $user
    }
    if ($HomeMDB -like '*Serv2*') {
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "Email_Server2" -Member $user
    }
    if ($HomeMDB -like '*Serv_Exchange3*') {
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "Email_Server3" -Member $user
    }
}
Write-Host "--------------------------------------------"
Write-Host $user "Exchange Mailbox Store::: $HomeMDB "
Write-Host "--------------------------------------------"
Read-Host -Prompt 'Press Enter to Exit'
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

The script looks fine. I would like to suggest you to give the input file  in below format (One below the other)

```
user1
user2
user3
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi thanks for replying, I have done this but get the following when running the script:       <code>   cmdlet ForEach-Object at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Process[0]:

Comment: Hi. Let us know where you corrected the script, after which it worked. It will be an learning for all